# смена текста после клика и ухода мыши с карточки

Tags: javascript

Нужно реализовать функцию changeTopTextCard которая при условии если был совершен клик на одну из карточек и после того как курсор мыши уходит с этой карточки, текст в блоке кликнутой карточки `<h3 class="card-cats__slogan"><span>Сказочное заморское яство</span></h3>` должен поменяться на '`TEST STRING'`

```js
const cardCats = document.querySelector('.card-section');

const star = function(event) {
  event.target.closest('.card-cats')
}

//Function change border card:
function changeColorBorder(event) {
  const target = event.target.closest('.card-cats');
  
  if (target === null) {
    return
  };
  
  target.querySelector('.card-cats__slogan').classList.toggle('changeBorder');
  target.querySelector('.card-cats__triangle').classList.toggle('changeBorderGradient');
  target.querySelector('.card-cats__main').classList.toggle('changeBorder');
  target.querySelector('.card-cats__image-circle').classList.toggle('changeBackground');
};

//Function to move the cursor from the card & change top text card:
function changeTopTextCard(event) {

  const target = event.target.closest('.card-cats');
 

  const cardText = target.querySelector('.card-cats__slogan > span');
  cardText.innerHTML = 'TEST STRING'

};



cardCats.addEventListener('click', changeColorBorder);
cardCats.addEventListener('mouseout', changeTopTextCard);
```

```css
.card-section {
  width 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.card-cats {
  width: 40%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

.card-cats__head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: green;
}

.changeBorder {
  color: #D91667;
  background-color: orange;
}
.changeBorderGradient {
  font-size 100px;
 }
    
.changeBackground {
  background-color: #D91667;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-section">

        <div class="card-cats">
          <div class="card-cats__head">
            <div class="card-cats__triangle"></div>
            <h3 class="card-cats__slogan"><span>Сказочное заморское яство</span></h3>
          </div>

          <div class="card-cats__main">
            <h3 class="card-cats__title">Товар 1</h3>
            <p class="card-cats__subtitile">с рыбой</p>
            <ul class="card-cats__properti">
              <li class="card-cats__properti-item">40 порций</li>
              <li class="card-cats__properti-item">2 мыши в подарок</li>
            </ul>

            <img class="card-cats__image-cat" src="img/home/section-card/cats-logo.svg">
            <div class="card-cats__image-circle">
              <p class="card-cats__image-circle-top">2</p>
              <p class="card-cats__image-circle-bottom">кг</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <span class="card-cats__bottom">
            Чего сидишь? порадуй кота, 
            <span class="card-cats__bottom-btn">
              <a href="#0" class="card-cats__bottom-btn-link"> купи</a>.
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        
                <div class="card-cats">
          <div class="card-cats__head">
            <div class="card-cats__triangle"></div>
            <h3 class="card-cats__slogan"><span>Сказочное заморское яство</span></h3>
          </div>

          <div class="card-cats__main">
            <h3 class="card-cats__title">Товар 2</h3>
            <p class="card-cats__subtitile">с мясом</p>
            <ul class="card-cats__properti">
              <li class="card-cats__properti-item">40 порций</li>
              <li class="card-cats__properti-item">2 мыши в подарок</li>
            </ul>

            <img class="card-cats__image-cat" src="img/home/section-card/cats-logo.svg">
            <div class="card-cats__image-circle">
              <p class="card-cats__image-circle-top">2</p>
              <p class="card-cats__image-circle-bottom">кг</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <span class="card-cats__bottom">
            Чего сидишь? порадуй кота, 
            <span class="card-cats__bottom-btn">
              <a href="#0" class="card-cats__bottom-btn-link"> купи</a>.
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: Я вам писал, что возвращает `closest`, перечитайте и попробуйте сделать сами.

Comment: И не проще вместо добавления класса всем элементам, добавить только на `card-cats` и в зависимости от него плясать в `css`?

Comment: В том случае closest сработал, сейчас вот пример (+ добавил в песочницу):

```
function changeTopTextCard(event) {
  const target = event.target.closest('.card-cats');
  target.querySelector('.card-cats__slogan > span').innerHTML = 'TEST STRING?'
};
cardCats.addEventListener('mouseout', changeTopTextCard);
```

closest возвращает нужный ~.card-cats~, но все работает не совсем так как нужно.

Comment: Ну проверяйте у `card-cats` еще и класс, который вешается при клике.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос  решен добавлением слушателя на сами карточки.

А что вы имелии ввиду про 'И не проще вместо добавления класса всем элементам, добавить только на card-cats и в зависимости от него плясать в css? – 
Oliver Patterson'

 Не совсем понял о добавлении какого класса на все элементы вы говоите ?

Comment: ```target.querySelector('.card-cats__slogan').classList.toggle('changeBorder');  target.querySelector('.card-cats__triangle').classList.toggle('changeBorderGradient');  target.querySelector('.card-cats__main').classList.toggle('changeBorder'); target.querySelector('.card-cats__image-circle').classList.toggle('changeBackground');``` не проще добавить вместо этого, класс на родителя и в `css` в завсимости от этого класса, задать стили детям?

Comment: это просто пример из интернета) в реальном проекте все на одном классе. Спасибо за подсказки по closest.